# JSoup: extracting text and store it in multiple variables

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

i have the following situation:

I want to extract all text between the "span" tags

```
<div class="examplediv">
<ul>
<li><span>1</span></li>
<li><span>2</span></li>
<li><span>3</span></li>
<li><span>4</span></li>                                     
</ul>
</div>

<div class="examplediv">
<ul>
<li><span>5</span></li>
<li><span>6</span></li>
<li><span>7</span></li>
<li><span>8</span></li>                                     
</ul>
</div>

<div class="examplediv">
<ul>
<li><span>9</span></li>
<li><span>10</span></li>
<li><span>11</span></li>
<li><span>12</span></li>                                     
</ul>
</div>

<div class="examplediv">
<ul>
<li><span>13</span></li>
<li><span>14</span></li>
<li><span>15</span></li>
<li><span>16</span></li>                                     
</ul>
</div>
```

Where all the first lines are going to be stored in variable "A", all the second lines in "B", all the third lines in "C" and so on.

My Java code is as follows:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
Elements exa = doc.select(".examplediv span");
if (exa != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < exa.size(); i++) {
A[i] = exa.get(i).text();
      }
}
```

This code puts all lines in variable "A".

```
A = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
```

And i want it to be stored like this:

```
A = 1,5,9,13
B = 2,6,10,14
C = 3,7,11,15
D = 4,8,12,16
```

Please give me some advice on how to do this. Thanks and Happy Holidays.

EDIT ---------------------------------

I had this idea:

```
if (exa != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < exa.size(); i++) {
A[i] = exa.get(0).text();
B[i] = exa.get(1).text();
C[i] = exa.get(2).text();
D[i] = exa.get(3).text();
      }
}
```

It gives me

```
A = 1,2,3,4
B = 1,2,3,4
C = 1,2,3,4
D = 1,2,3,4
```

It repeats the first 4 spans.

How can i at least get:

```
A = 1,2,3,4
B = 5,6,7,8
C = 9,10,11,12
D = 13,14,15,16
```

Comment: Well you didn't say you wanted arrays. Check my update.

Comment: Wait. What you are doing makes no sense. The exa size is the number of your spans. It's completely wrong what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using String

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        try {
            String text = "<div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>1</span></li> <li><span>2</span></li> <li><span>3</span></li> <li><span>4</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>5</span></li> <li><span>6</span></li> <li><span>7</span></li> <li><span>8</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>9</span></li> <li><span>10</span></li> <li><span>11</span></li> <li><span>12</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>13</span></li> <li><span>14</span></li> <li><span>15</span></li> <li><span>16</span></li> </ul> </div>";
            String A = "", B = "", C = "", D = "";

            Document page = Jsoup.parse(text, "UTF-8");

            Elements uls = page.select(".examplediv ul");

            for(Element ul : uls) {
                Elements spans = ul.select("span");
                A += spans.get(0).text() + ",";
                B += spans.get(1).text() + ",";
                C += spans.get(2).text() + ",";
                D += spans.get(3).text() + ",";
            }

            A = A.substring(0, A.length() - 1);
            B = B.substring(0, B.length() - 1);
            C = C.substring(0, C.length() - 1);
            D = D.substring(0, D.length() - 1);

            System.out.println(A);
            System.out.println(B);
            System.out.println(C);
            System.out.println(D);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Using StringBuilder

```
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

        try {
            String text = "<div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>1</span></li> <li><span>2</span></li> <li><span>3</span></li> <li><span>4</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>5</span></li> <li><span>6</span></li> <li><span>7</span></li> <li><span>8</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>9</span></li> <li><span>10</span></li> <li><span>11</span></li> <li><span>12</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>13</span></li> <li><span>14</span></li> <li><span>15</span></li> <li><span>16</span></li> </ul> </div>";
            StringBuilder A = new StringBuilder(), B = new StringBuilder(), C = new StringBuilder(), D = new StringBuilder();

            Document page = Jsoup.parse(text, "UTF-8");

            Elements uls = page.select(".examplediv ul");

            for(Element ul : uls) {
                Elements spans = ul.select("span");
                A.append(spans.get(0).text() + ",");
                B.append(spans.get(1).text() + ",");
                C.append(spans.get(2).text() + ",");
                D.append(spans.get(3).text() + ",");
            }

            A.deleteCharAt(A.length() - 1);
            B.deleteCharAt(B.length() - 1);
            C.deleteCharAt(C.length() - 1);
            D.deleteCharAt(D.length() - 1);

            System.out.println(A);
            System.out.println(B);
            System.out.println(C);
            System.out.println(D);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

The reason of that behavior is because you use = and not += so you overwrite the value you previously had.
Maybe this is what you want.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {

    try {
        String text = "<div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>1</span></li> <li><span>2</span></li> <li><span>3</span></li> <li><span>4</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>5</span></li> <li><span>6</span></li> <li><span>7</span></li> <li><span>8</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>9</span></li> <li><span>10</span></li> <li><span>11</span></li> <li><span>12</span></li> </ul> </div> <div class=\"examplediv\"> <ul> <li><span>13</span></li> <li><span>14</span></li> <li><span>15</span></li> <li><span>16</span></li> </ul> </div>";
        ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>(), B = new ArrayList<String>(), C = new ArrayList<String>(), D = new ArrayList<String>();

        Document page = Jsoup.parse(text, "UTF-8");

        Elements uls = page.select(".examplediv ul");

        for(Element ul : uls) {
            Elements lis = ul.select("span");
            A.add(lis.get(0).text());
            B.add(lis.get(1).text());
            C.add(lis.get(2).text());
            D.add(lis.get(3).text());
        }

        for(String str : A) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        } System.out.println("");

        for(String str : B) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        } System.out.println("");

        for(String str : C) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        } System.out.println("");

        for(String str : D) {
            System.out.print(str + " ");
        } System.out.println("");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Huh? Maybe you could elaborate a little?

Comment: The code I provided does exactly what you described. So, where is the problem?

Comment: Check the new section.